# Solve a problem when pressing a button, more than one button is responded to

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

In a list of rows inside the recyclerview, I used the button operator to celebrate and appear every time I press it. I defined it to work inside the viewholder and the code works. But there is a problem when I press the first button. It and button number 18 are responded to at the same time. How do I avoid redundancy?

```
public void onBindViewHolder ( RecyclerViewAdapterBookA.catViewHolderBookA holder , int position ) {

    BookA a = bookAS.get ( position );

    holder.img.setImageResource ( a.getImg ( ) );
    holder.text1.setText ( a.getText1 ( ) );
    holder.text2.setText ( a.getText2 ( ) );
    holder.img2.setImageResource ( a.getImg2 ( ) );
    holder.img3.setImageResource ( a.getImg3 ( ) );
    holder.img2.setTag ( 0 );


    holder.img2.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick ( View view ) {
            final int status = (Integer) view.getTag ();
            switch (status) {
                case 0:
                   holder.img3.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
                    Toast.makeText ( view.getContext ( ) , "تم تعليمه گ مقروء" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ( );
                    view.setTag ( 1 );
                    break;
                case 1:
                    holder.img3.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
                    Toast.makeText ( view.getContext ( ) , "تم تعليمه گ غير مقروء" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ( );
                    view.setTag ( 0 );
                    break;
            }



        }

    } );




  


}
```

Comment: have been solved
Just add a method in your adapter class after the get Item Count method    

@Override
    public in t get I t e m View Type(in t position) {
        return position;
    }

Comment: Please post your solution in a separate answer. That will help future visitors to find it, ensure that it's preserved (comment may be deleted at any time) and that also fits the format of this site